# Combine two or more columns into a new column by row condition

Tags: pandas

I would like to combine two or more columns into a new columns, based on the row condition ( which is 1, an integer ) the new columns should be a column contains joined string.

I tried using nonzero to filter our row with zero but fail.

```py
index LAWSUIT BOARD-MEETING
A          1    0
B          0    0
C          1    1
D          0    1
```

Tried this, but it just combined all index:

```py
rdf['NEW'] = rdf.apply(lambda x: ','.join(x.index) if x.nonzero() else 0, axis=1)
```

Expected the "NEW" columns should look like this:

```py
index LAWSUIT BOARD-MEETING   NEW
A          1    0             LAWSUIT
B          0    0
C          1    1             LAWSUIT,BOARD-MEETING
D          0    1             BOARD-MEETING
```

Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
final=df.assign(NEW=(df.dot(df.columns+',').str[:-1]))
```

---

```
       LAWSUIT  BOARD-MEETING                    NEW
index                                               
A            1              0                LAWSUIT
B            0              0                       
C            1              1  LAWSUIT,BOARD-MEETING
D            0              1          BOARD-MEETING
```

Comment: Thanks !! This is nice and neat !

Comment: Thanks, I am quite new to "ask" questions in here. Though I have already browsing stackoverflow for over five years.

Comment: @modernxart Sure :) no problem, Cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

This is one of the few things that a `for` loop would be appropriate for in pandas

```
col_names = rdf.columns.tolist()
rdf["NEW"] = ""

for col in col_names:
    rdf.loc[rdf[col] == 1, "NEW"] = rdf.loc[rdf[col] == 1, "NEW"] + ("," + col)

rdf["NEW"] = rdf["NEW"].str.strip(",")
```

Comment: for loop is good for code reading, but not what i am looking for. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

This could do the job

```
rdf['New'] = rdf.replace(1, pd.Series(rdf.columns+',', rdf.columns)).\
                                           replace(0, '').sum(axis = 1).\
                                           str.strip(',')
```